# $150 lacks in my wage

Tags: word-usage

The employer did not transfer all my wage this month because he miscounted. Which is correct?

> $150 **lacks** in my wage.

or

> I am **missing** $150 of my wage.

Comment: First of all, the dollar sign goes ***before* the dollar value** in English.

Comment: *$150 is lacking from my wage.*

Comment: A hundred and fifty bucks is missing out of my paycheck and I'd better have it on Monday, you hear me you greedy old bastard?

Comment: In some countries, if you say `150 lacks` people will think you're asking for 15 million dollars (one "lakh", which sounds like "lack", is ten thousand)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first one certainly isn't correct. If A lacks B, then A is missing B, not the other way around. The way your first option is phrased right now, the $150 **lacks in** your wage...which doesn't make much sense.

Even if we were to fix the ordering issue and make it, "My wage lacks $150," that sounds unnatural in English. It is technically correct, but doesn't sound great.

Your second option is much better:

> I am missing $150 of my wages.

Note that the dollar sign goes BEFORE the numerical value. Even though we say "150 dollars," we write "$150."

Though for politeness' sake, I would go with a slightly wordier phrasing:

> I think I may be missing $150 of my wages. I was supposed to get paid $___ this month, but only received $____ in my bank account.

Answer (score 9):

I would turn this around completely and say something like:

> My wages are $150 short.

Or indirectly asking for an explanation:

> My wages seem to be $150 short.

Comment: Or you could say "My wages are short *by* $150.".